# Php for loop Onclick function for each function event

Tags: javascript, php

I have repost my question again. I have a for loop in my main page which loop through a list of result with show and hide button (onclick function). Whenever I click on the any of show() button, all my div.view slide down togather and when I click on hide() button, all my div.vew slide up togather. I would like to have each show() corresponding to each div.view tag. I sorry about my bad english and repost the question again due lack of experience in my coding. Would appreciate if anyone can help me here. thanks alot.

Hide
[image]

show
[image]

```
   <?php
   for( $i = 0; $i < count($db); $i++)
   {   
   <div class="view">
   <?php
   echo $data["Description"];
   ?>
   </div>


    <div style="float:right; margin:0px 8px 0px 0px;">
    <div onClick="show()" style="cursor:pointer; font-size:12px; color:#8080FF; float:left;">Show&nbsp;<div style="color:#FFF; font-weight:bold; float:right;">/</div></div>
    <div onClick="hide()" style="cursor:pointer; font-size:12px; color:#8080FF; float:right;">&nbsp;Hide</div>
    </div>

   }
   ?>
```

search.js

```
   function show() 
   {    
   $('div.view').animate({height:160},500);
   }

   function hide() 
   {
   $('div.view').animate({height:40},500);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you want to show/hide each div individually when you click on a link.
In order to do so you have to pass a parameter identifying the div you want to work on. Fortunately, you have such parameter already in your code, it's the index of your loop. Yo can add it to your code this way

```
<div onClick="show(<?=$i?>)">show</div>
```

Then you have to change your jQuery function to use the parameter

```
function show(index) 
{    
    $('div.view').eq(index).animate({height:160},500);
}
```

This way, when you click on a link you will only show the div referenced by this link.

There is a better way to do this however. You should not mix html and function call but add events listener to your DOM elements. You also should avoid styling your elements with the style attribute but use CSS class instead.

Comment: Thank you sebastien maloron i solved the problem after a few troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do this. You can change your "show()" to "show(this)" in your HTML and your JS code to:

```
function show(obj) {
    $(obj).parent().animate({height: 160}, 500);
}
```

Or, add an identifying class to your Show and Hide buttons, then in JS create an event like this:

```
$('.show').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().animate({height: 160}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Thank you bro, for your answer it work too, but the above answer is more suitable for me. thank you